# Where is the VS2008 static and import library documentation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, static-libraries

Looking through the MSDN documentation that ships with VS2008 I can find no detailed documention that relates to static and import libraries. Specifically the trade offs of dynamic vs static libraries and the implications of each with respect to CRT version dependencies, memory sharing and exception handling etc.

If memory serves there used to be loads of documation about this stuff in previous versions of VS, now there appears to be nothing more detailed than a page that describes which buttons to press to create a static library project and add a class to it!

I see plenty of documentation relating to the MFC (when VS2008 doesn't even support MFC anymore), and plenty of documentation relating to Dotnet, but almost nothing relating to C++ development beyond the core language and library references.

I haven't found anything useful by Googling either, although I possibly just haven't yet found the seach string that returns information gold.

Anyone got links to some good overviews please?

Comment: "when VS2008 doesn't even support MFC anymore" In what way does VS2008 not support MFC? It still ships with MFC. And 2008 SP1 delivered a pretty significant MFC update.

Comment: My guess: Visual Studio Express Edition?

Comment: The whole point of the MFC is to simplify development of GUI and COM applications, it did this via the inclusion of extensive wizard support. The ClassWizard used to enable Automation methods to be easily added to MFC classes. All of that Wizard support was silently dropped several version of VS ago, so all the framework code in the MFC that enabled that wizard support is now just dead cruft. Not that that is the the real topic of this question.

Answer (score 0):

The [Visual C++ Walkthroughs page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w9eycd%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) contains plentify resources, naming a few relevant ones:

- [Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Static Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

There are more relevant articles on the [Building a C/C++ Program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7kx322x%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) page as well (on building isolated applications, thus relevant to statically linking and Side-By-Side deployments).

Comment: Thanks but what you've linked here is the documentation that I already referred to which describes nothing more than which buttons to press to create a new project. I need something much more in depth.

Answer (score 0):

> Looking through the MSDN documentation that ships with VS2008 I can
>   find no detailed documention that relates to static and import
>   libraries. Specifically the trade offs of dynamic vs static libraries
>   and the implications of each with respect to CRT version dependencies,
>   memory sharing and exception handling etc.

Doing a search for "CRT libraries" on msdn.com gives me this as the first result:

[C Run-Time Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx)

Which has quite a bit of information about the static vs. dynamic versions of the CRT libraries.

For information about dynamic link libraries, you're looking for [this page on DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ez7dh12.aspx).

There's also a page called ["Building C/C++ Isolated Applications and Side-by-side Assemblies"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235532.aspx) which discusses the advantages of using static libaries (that's how you make isolated applications).

> If memory serves there used to be loads of documation about this stuff
>   in previous versions of VS, now there appears to be nothing more
>   detailed than a page that describes which buttons to press to create a
>   static library project and add a class to it!

Doing a search for "static library" on msdn.com gives me this as the first result:

[Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Static Library (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx)

As the title says, it is a step-by-step procedure on how to make static libraries straight from the horse's mouth.

Comment: Same applies here as the comment I just made to Sehe. I don't need to know which button to press to create a static library project, I'm looking for documention describing static libraries in depth. I'm also specifically _not_ looking for information on DLLs or the CRT.